# How do I get black to stay black?

Tags: light, shaders, lighting

My intent is to have a black letter on a bright white background.  I have played around with lighting, roughness, etc but I just can't get the clean colors I want - just these different shades of grey.  The image is below, as well as the shaders.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here's the image.

[image]

Here's the shader for the black.

[image]

Here's the shader for the white.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Eevee or Cycles?

Comment: Eevee - is there a way to get it to render the colors accurately?  Cycles is really slow!

Comment: Looks like Bloom with a large radius? Is the color bleeding in from the light background? Try switching it off in the EEVEE render panel.

Comment: @RobinBetts turning Bloom off has very little effect.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Switching off filmic in render=>color management seems to help.

Comment: Do you want reflections and shadows or plain black and white like a 2d drawing?

Comment: Use an Emission node and it won't be affected by the lights

Comment: I show black with the material settings as shown.. the effect must have an external origin? Nothing happening in the compositor? No mist? If no fix, share a sample .blend showing the effect at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/